# simpUserRegistry.getUsers() is empty web sockets

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, websocket

I am trying to implement notifications on a website using web sockets. I have configured the server configuration and sending messages. My client receives my messages and renders on the page, but when I try to get a list of users connected to the socket, I get an empty list.

My config:

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EnableWebSocket
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

@Override
public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry config) {
    config.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/user");
    config.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
}

@Override
public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
    registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
            .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
}
}
```

My Rest controller for send message:

```
@RestController
@CrossOrigin("*")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping("/notifications")
public class NotificationController {

private final NotificationService notificationService;

@PostMapping("/all")
public void sendNotificationToAll(@RequestBody String message) {
    notificationService.sendToAll(message);
}

@PostMapping("/user")
public void sendNotificationToUser(@RequestBody String message) {
    notificationService.sendToUsers(message);
}

@GetMapping("/getUser")
public void getUsers(){
    notificationService.getUsers();
}
}
```

Service for sending messages to topic:

```
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NotificationService {

private final SimpMessagingTemplate simpMessagingTemplate;
private final SimpUserRegistry simpUserRegistry;

public void sendToAll(String message) {
    System.out.println(message);
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/public", message);
}

public void sendToUsers(String message) {
    List<String> users = List.of("some user fullName");
    simpMessagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(users.get(0), "queue/private", message);
}

public void getUsers() {
    List<String> userNames = simpUserRegistry.getUsers().stream().map(SimpUser::getName).toList();
    simpUserRegistry.getUsers().forEach(System.out::println);
}
}
```

I tried to send the client's unique name when connecting, it didn't help.
I use SockJs for js client.

Comment: From the [javascript tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/javascript/info): "*[JavaScript] is unrelated to the Java programming language and shares only superficial similarities. ...*" --- Due to the implied meaning, I strongly recommend to rename class `SimpUserRegistry` to e.g. `SimpleUserRegistry`.

Comment: @Turing85 SimpUserRegistry its Spring Framework class. So SimpleUserRegistry doesn't exist

Comment: Oh wow... what a blunder... haven't expected that from the spring-team...